# How do I query subcollections firestore ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I want to make a query to a sub-collection in firestore I have the following structure

```
"groups": {
        "g1":
        {
          "name": "Group 1",
          "users": {
              "u1": {
                          "id": "user1"
                    },
              "u2": {
                          "id": "user2"
                    }
             }
      },
     "g2":
        {
          "name": "Group 2",
          "users": {
              "u1": {
                          "id": "user1"
                    }
            }
       }

 }

"users": {
    "user1": {
                "firstName": "Lorem",
                "lastName": "Lorem"
             },

    "user2": {
                "firstName": "Lorem2",
                "lastName": "Lorem2"
             }

}
```

and I want to make a query that looking for user1 brings me the groups that belong that user in the example would bring me g1 and g2 but if I look for user2 should I only bring g1 can you create a composite index between the group and the user? I am developing it in ionic 4 I don't know if the data is well structured

Thank you very much in what you can help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`array_contains` operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) on field `users`. All that requires is that you know the complete, exact element that the array should contains. If you know all of that, you can check with::

```
groupsRef.where("users", "array-contains", {
    u1": {
        "id": "user1"
    }
})
```

If you only know `"user1"`, you will need to have an array that contains only `"user1"`. So for example:

```
"userids": ["user1", "user2"]
```

Then you can query with:

```
itiesRef.where("regions", "array-contains", "user1")
```